# website that used to work suddenly throwing jquery "uncaught syntaxErrors"

Tags: javascript, jquery, syntax-error, typeerror, uncaught-exception

I've helped a friend 3 years ago to develop a small website. It worked perfectly until some days ago. I've found by inspecting it, that it throws a bunch of jQuery syntax errors (also related to other jQuery plugins).

The errors displayed on the console are:

```
Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token,                             jquery.colorbox-min.js:4
Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected number                         jquery.orbit-1.2.3.min.js:10
Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier                               ddsmoothmenu.js:33
Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier                     jquery.tipTip.minified.js:21
Uncaught TypeError: Property '$' of object [object Object] is not a function      (index):30
```

I as was saying, this was workin ok. I assume it has to do with the versions or the browser, but I'm not sure where to start.

Thanks in advance

Comment: [Something in your website doesn't work right?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/125997/something-in-my-web-site-or-project-doesnt-work-can-i-just-paste-a-link-to-it) Here's a helpful link.

Comment: recommend: load first css then js

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't know who has been playing around with your files, but they seem to be corrupted.

If you replace them with CDN/online versions:

```
<!-- COLORBOX -->
<script src="http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery.colorbox/1.4.3/jquery.colorbox-min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

<!-- ORBIT -->
<script src="http://zurb.com/playground/uploads/upload/upload/208/jquery.orbit.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

<!-- MENU -->
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://www.dynamicdrive.com/dynamicindex1/ddsmoothmenu.js"></script>

<!-- TOOLTIP -->
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://cdn.jsdelivr.net/tiptip/1.3/jquery.tipTip.minified.js"></script>
```

and take jQuery out of noConflict mode:

```
//$.noConflict();
```

Your site will work again.

You can then make sure the versions are correct before downloading them once again and host them on your servers.

Comment: A bit strange, no one 'supposedly' touched it. I have a backup at home, I'll check the files and come back. Thanks for pointing this!

Comment: Compared the files on the hosting with the ones i had as backup and indeed, the ones online were corrupted- For example, all plus signs (+) were replaced with a blank... weird, still don't know what caused that, but by replacing the files everything started working again. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

It seems that jQuery is missing (at least from this page's perspective). That is indicated by the last error you see about the '$'. Please confirm the presence and version-correctness of jQuery.

Comment: Just checked the source: jQuery is definitely there and included in the correct order.

Comment: Please add: 
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.7/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>

Comment: That will make zero difference.